# Jetty Session Clustering with a Database

Tags: database, session, jetty-9

I have setup Session Clustering based on https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jetty/jetty-session-clustering-example/ and https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/session-clustering-jdbc.html using database to persist the sessions. I have launched two instances of jetty 9 on my local and it is working fine. When I logged in in Server A. Then force stop Server A, I am redirected to Server B in which I am still login. But when I tried to add another jetty instance in cluster which is running on different machine/ip let say Server C. If I am loggin to Server A, then tries to stop Server A and Server B. I am redirected to Server C but without session. So I end up in the login page of Server C. I have checked the database and the Server C creates a new session row instead of reusing the session created in Server A. I dont know what configuration I have missed.